# How to change square into triangle

Tags: javascript, html, css

I had given a project in which I had to change my div from a square into a triangle in Javascript.

I had to make a change when the user clicks on the color button it will change to green and when the user clicks on the shape button it should change the shape into a triangle

Below is my code which I tried by myself and I am unable to code for:

```js
var outerDiv = document.getElementById('outer');
var innerDiv = document.getElementById('inner');
var colorButton = document.getElementById('btn-1');
var shapeButton = document.getElementById('btn-2');
colorButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  outerDiv.style.backgroundColor = "green";
});

shapeButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  innerDiv.innerText = "Triangle"
});
```

```css
#outer {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0.5rem auto;
  background-color: #8a2be2;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

#inner {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 70px 0px 0px 72px;
}

button {
  width: 10rem;
  height: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 5px 30px 5px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

button:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 2px grey;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner"></div>
</div>

<button id="btn-1">Change Color</button>
<button id="btn-2">Change Shape</button>
```

Comment: This question has nothing to do about DOM. It has nothing to do with the HTML structure and even less with the DOM-Tree. You either want to use a canvas for this or look into CSS `clip-path`.

Comment: [change without any kind of animation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27786974/4935162)

Comment: When you say the shape is to change, is it to be a gradual change or instant? And is the element to change shape or just to look as though it has?

Comment: @AHaworth I don't think that matters much, given that it currently doesn't change shape _at all_.

Comment: @TylerH I asked because for a gradual shape change you’d probably need at least 4 points at all times, and then the way it would morph into a triangle would be set by where those points end up.  If it’s to be an instant switch then of course that doesn’t matter, just clip path for the triangle with 3 points will do.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to change the form is to use `clip-path` where you can use `polygon` to define coordinates and the elements outside of those coordinates will be cut away:

```css
.triangle {
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}
```

That class you can apply in JS with the usage of `classList` + `add` or `toggle`

```js
const OUTER_DIV = document.getElementById('outer'),
      INNER_DIV = document.getElementById('inner'),
      COLOR_BUTTON = document.getElementById('btn-1'),
      SHAPE_BUTTON = document.getElementById('btn-2');


COLOR_BUTTON.addEventListener('click', function() {
  OUTER_DIV.classList.toggle('bg-green');
});

SHAPE_BUTTON.addEventListener('click', function() {
  INNER_DIV.classList.toggle('triangle');
});
```

```css
[id="outer"] {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0.5rem auto;
  background-color: #8a2be2;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

#inner {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 70px 0px 0px 72px;
}

button {
  width: 10rem;
  height: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 5px 30px 5px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

button:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 2px grey;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.triangle {
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}

.bg-green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner"></div>
</div>

<button id="btn-1">Change Color</button>
<button id="btn-2">Change Shape</button>
```

It is better and the modern approach to use `classList` to apply visual changes through CSS.
I also refactored your code to use const instead of var as the elements are constant. I wrote const names capitalized for readability reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding the text, you can simply add a class to the inner div. This way you can style the inner div differently if it's supposed to be a triangle.

```
innerDiv.classList.add("triangle");
```

Then, in your CSS, you define custom styles for the case that the `innerDiv` has the `triangle`-class.
I used a simple "hack" using borders:

```
#inner.triangle {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 75px solid transparent;
  border-right: 75px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 150px solid white;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

This code is based on the code on https://css-tricks.com/the-shapes-of-css/#triangle-up, slightly modified to fit your site.
This is not the best way and it's not responsive, but I think it's fine in your case.

Here is the complete page again:

```js
var outerDiv = document.getElementById('outer');
var innerDiv = document.getElementById('inner');
var colorButton = document.getElementById('btn-1');
var shapeButton = document.getElementById('btn-2');
colorButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  outerDiv.style.backgroundColor = "green";
});

shapeButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  innerDiv.classList.add("triangle");
});
```

```css
#outer {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0.5rem auto;
  background-color: #8a2be2;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

#inner {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 70px 0px 0px 72px;
}

#inner.triangle {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 75px solid transparent;
  border-right: 75px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 150px solid white;
  background-color: transparent;
}

button {
  width: 10rem;
  height: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 5px 30px 5px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

button:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 2px grey;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner"></div>
</div>

<button id="btn-1">Change Color</button>
<button id="btn-2">Change Shape</button>
```

Comment: while this work I dont think there is a need to use a `hack` that does not allow any responsiveness. Also completely unnecessary. A "cleaner" hack would be the usage of pseudo-elements.

Comment: I agree. And I think using clip-path is much better. But the whole thing isn't responsive at all and looks like a school assignment to me. So I wanted to implement it using https://css-tricks.com/the-shapes-of-css so you can easily switch between different shapes.